# Object Error in Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am building a Macro in excel using a VBA Form. However as soon as I click on the command button the Object error shows up for the below mentioned code  for Part 1.

As I am building a code for the first time I have also refer to both the parts of the code. Any changes which are needed will be kindly appreciated

**Part 1**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

MRF.Show

End Sub
```

**Part 2**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'Empty AssignToBox
AssignTo.Value = ""

'Empty Zones
 Zones.Clear

'ZonesDatabase
 With Zones
.AddItem "North"
.AddItem "South"
.AddItem "Central"
.AddItem "West"
.AddItem "East"
.AddItem "CPC"
End With

'Empty Department
 Department.Value = ""

'Empty Designation
 Designation.Clear

'Designation Database
 With Designation
.AddItem "Assistant"
.AddItem "Senior Assistant"
.AddItem "Executive"
.AddItem "Senior Executive"
.AddItem "Assistant Manager"
.AddItem "Associate Manager"
.AddItem "Manager"
.AddItem "Senior Manager"
.AddItem "Chief Manager"
.AddItem "Assistant Vice President"
.AddItem "Associate Vice President"
.AddItem "Vice President"
.AddItem "Senior Vice President"
.AddItem "Executive Vice President"
 End With

  'Empty Grade
   Grade.Clear

   'Grade Database
 With Grade
.AddItem "7B"
.AddItem "7A"
.AddItem "6B"
.AddItem "6A"
.AddItem "5B"
.AddItem "5A"
.AddItem "4B"
.AddItem "4A"
.AddItem "3B"
.AddItem "3A"
.AddItem "2B"
.AddItem "2A"
.AddItem "1B"
.AddItem "1A"
 End With

'Empty Location
 Location.Value = ""

 'Empty ProfileShortlisted
  ProfileShortlisted.Value = ""

  'Empty ProfileLinedUp
  ProfileLinedUp.Value = ""

  'Empty ShortlistedForInterview
   ShortListedforInterview.Value = ""

  'Empty Status
   Status.Clear

  'StatusDatabase
  With Status
.AddItem "Open"
.AddItem "Close"
.AddItem "WIP"
.AddItem "Joined"
 End With

 'Empty Remark
   Remark.Value = ""

  End Sub

  Private Sub ok_Click()

   Dim emptyRow As Long

     'Checklist active
  Checklist.Activate

  'Determine emptyRow
   emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

   'Transfer information
    Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = AssignTo.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = Zones.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = Department.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = Desigantion.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = Grade.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = RequestDate.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = Location.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = ProfileShortlisted.Value 
    Cells(emptyRow, 9).Value = ProfileLinedUp.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 10).Value = ShortListedforInterview.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 11).Value = OfferedDate.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 12).Value = DateOfJoining.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 13).Value = Status.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 14).Value = Remarks.Value

   End Sub
      'Empty Remarks
       Remarks.Value = ""

   End Sub
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to implement userForms: Remove your Part 1 code, and instead place the following code into a new **module** (not a userForm). It seems you have a series of listBoxes and textBoxes and that you've named your userForm `MRF`.  As long as all items within that userForm are named as you have in your code (Part 2, which should be in the userForm), it should now work.  Test by placing your cursor in the `main()` sub below and then stepping through the code.  You'll see that when it reaches the `Set dLog = New MRF` line, it will jump to the userForm, run the  `UserForm_Initialize()` code, and then the userForm should appear filled with the items in the  `UserForm_Initialize()` sub.  Hope that helps.

```
Option Explicit
Public dLog As MRF
Sub main()
Set dLog = New MRF
With dLog
  .Show
End With
End Sub
```